# Uploading a bitmap from android to a server results in an unopenable file

Tags: java, android, bitmap, wamp

So I've used some code from stackoverflow that uses HttpURLConnection to send a bitmap from Android to my local WAMP server. The only issue I have is that the data being sent can't be open by an image viewer. I have a feeling it has to do with the method that I am sending the data.

```
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
    URL url = new URL(ip+urls[0]);
    httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty(
            "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + this.boundary);

    DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(
            httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

    request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
            this.attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" +
            this.attachmentFileName + "\"" + this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes(this.crlf);

    int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
    Log.e("bitmap bytes",Integer.toString(bytes));
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    byte[] pixels = buffer.array();

    request.write(pixels);
    request.writeBytes(this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary +
            this.twoHyphens + this.crlf);
    request.flush();
    request.close();

    //Response
    InputStream responseStream = new
            BufferedInputStream(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream());

    BufferedReader responseStreamReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    responseStreamReader.close();

    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
    responseStream.close();
    httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
    return response;
```

I have checked the file sizes and they are the same. I plan on sending the image back to my android device in the future, however I wanted to make sure the uploading part worked first. If the file is supposed to be unopenable and I'm understanding the code wrong I apologize for the wasted time.